# How to change a particular column value for certain number of rows in Pig latin

Tags: apache-pig

I have a a pig file with say 10000 rows. Is there any quick way where I can change the value of a certain column for say first 1000 rows ?

Answer (score 1):

Since some info is missing, I will make a few assumptions, and then offer a solution.

- by "first 1000 rows" you mean that you can order them records using some column
- you which to change the value of column `$1` in first 1000 records when ordering by column `$2`

The following code snippet will do what you asked for:

```
    a = load ...
    b = rank a by $2;
    c = foreach b generate $0, (rank_a<1000?$1:3*$1), $2..;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use For Each and Limit Operations to achieve the effect.